# How can I implement Custom Datepicker using Bootstrap and Angular?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

After searching for some time, I am getting the normal [datepickers](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), and I am not sure how to customize it?

If anyone one knows how to customize it, please let me know.

Comment: bootstrap-datetimepicker.css in this file you can customize

Answer (score 0):

You can customize via adding css class.
If there will be problem with rewrite i suggest to use `!important`